# Can a crystal grow or propagate faster than 'c'?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, quantum

We have, perhaps, all experienced those 'heat' packs wherein a local disturbance causes a crystal structure to rapidly dissipate through the medium, releasing heat in the process. Nothing really 'moves' from one point in the pack to another, except the physical transformation into a crystalline like structure.

Now consider this happening as a result of quantum effects, perhaps quantum tunneling, quantum entanglement, or other unknown quantum effect. Consider also that this might be happening in some unknown medium or matter such as dark matter. This question is not about the '*how*' or the '*method*'.

Is there any practical or theoretical constraint that absolutely prevents any form of crystal from propagating in a structure whose boundary 'grows' faster than a speed '**c**'?

For instance (for illustrative purposes but not limited to), maybe one atom (or whatever dark matter particles would be called once we find them) becomes a seed that causes a bond to form with a neighboring dark matter particle through quantum tunneling, which forms a bond with another neighboring dark matter particle (anthropomorphizing, "Oh, my, a particle just appeared in me, so I must do this" type of thing), and so on, forming some form of crystal lattice, that is propagating away from the original seed at a speed that exceeds '**c**'? Since nothing is actually traveling faster than '**c**' (the quantum tunneling particle does not *move* from A to B, it just appears at B, never really having been at A in the first place) except the arrangement of particles (perhaps an almost instantaneous chain reaction of quantum  effects), and no information is actually traveling faster than '**c**' (because nothing was known or defined about the particle until it *appeared* at point B), is there any specific law or principle or equation or theory or model in the existing physics textbook that ***prevents*** this from happening?

This is ***NOT*** about any limitation proscribed by any existing known theories of crystal formation and atomic bond formation in known substances, but about a *limitation* based on universal principles that would apply to ***ANY*** form of bond formation in ***ANY*** substance, known or unknown.

Please note, this is not asking 'could it happen' or 'how would it happen' or 'what are the conditions under which it would happen'. It is asking if there is anything we positively universally theoretically accept as fact that would **prevent** it from happening, notwithstanding we don't know **how** it would happen?

***EDIT***

**TLDR**

This question seems to have generated some controversy, based on misapprehension of the question. It is founded on a very complex concept, not always readily apparent. Here is a thought experiment that illustrates and perhaps clarifies the basis of it.

"Wormhole' technology and entanglement have generally been accepted as potentially possible. Imagine an infinite number of wormholes (folds in space/time) joining the seed node to an infinite number of 'particles', perhaps of dark matter, of which we hypothesize exists but we know very little about. The 'crystalization trigger' that changes the particles into a crystal 'structure' travels through these worm holes to every 'target' at 'relatively' the same 'time'. It would appear to an universal observer that the crystal had formed almost instantaneously, everywhere, and would certainly have 'grown' faster than the speed '**c**' - limited by the speed of travel through a wormhole. (However, the information about such a formation would not reach the observer any faster than '**c**'). But, like Einstein said, things can appear to one observer as being very different to how the same thing appears to another observer.

My research and knowledge has not revealed any principle or limitation that is posited by the current physics textbook that precludes this thought experiment from happening in reality. The limitation on the speed of information and matter to less than '**c**' is through the normal unfolded space/time, and that seems to be generally accepted. It is my understanding that it does not necessarily apply to folded space/time situations.

The question is, beyond the accepted 'laws' that neither information nor matter can travel through normal space/time faster than the speed '**c**', are there any other specific limitations to '**c**' that would also apply to, say, wormholes and entanglement?

Incidentally, there are some good and sound speculations that posit 'entanglement' is actually an occurrence of a 'wormhole' or fold in space/time such that even though these two particles appear to us in normal space/time to be a great distance apart, they are really side-by-each in the quantum 'folded universe' world. An infinite number of 'wormholes' is thus not beyond current conjecture, just like dark matter, even though our anthropic viewpoint cannot 'detect' them.

An insight into this concept is given by

> A Cryptic Equation
>   The new wormhole work began in 2013, when Jafferis attended an intriguing talk at the Strings conference in South Korea. The speaker, Juan Maldacena, a professor of physics at the Institute for Advanced Study in Princeton, New Jersey, had recently concluded, based on various hints and arguments, that “ER = EPR.” That is, wormholes between distant points in space-time, the simplest of which are called Einstein-Rosen or “ER” bridges, are equivalent (albeit in some ill-defined way) to entangled quantum particles, also known as Einstein-Podolsky-Rosen or “EPR” pairs. The ER = EPR conjecture, posed by Maldacena and Leonard Susskind of Stanford, was an attempt to solve the modern incarnation of the infamous black hole information paradox by tying space-time geometry, governed by general relativity, to the instantaneous quantum connections between far-apart particles that Einstein called “spooky action at a distance.” https://www.quantamagazine.org/newfound-wormhole-allows-information-to-escape-black-holes-20171023/

Comment: By "c" do you mean the speed of light?

Comment: If the crystal is big like a galaxy cluster, it will grow up (expand to be correctly) faster than 'c' due to universe expansion. But of course a so big crystal cannot exist, and if you try to create it it will collapse due to gravity.

Comment: "consider this happening as a result of quantum effects, perhaps quantum tunneling, quantum entanglement, or other unknown quantum effect" - are you asking us to consider science that does not exist yet?

Comment: I mean 'C' the constant, the universal speed limit of the universe. It is just coincidentally the speed of light under certain conditions.

Comment: @Stefano Balzarotti  You are assuming that it is made of matter that has mass. Apparently, many will argue that dark matter cannot exist, yet many will also argue that it does.

Comment: @Alexander you need to get a thicker physics text book. Two of those have been 'proven' to exist, many more qualities have been hypothesized under different models, but have bot been 'discovered;, thus they are not 'known to exist'. Actually, ALL science 'exists', whether we know of it or not. It doesn't suddenly 'exist' just because we 'discover' it. Unless, of course, you mean 'only if we look at it, it exists' quantum physics style.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond I can't understand the relation with dark matter, Anyway as far as we know all fermions have mass. What do you want a crystal made of bosons?

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second I mean specifically "faster than light" aspects of these phenomena. And I would disagree with "ALL science 'exists'" statement. While all physical laws do exist, science is an intelligent construct describing these laws, and its development can be tracked and dated throughout history.

Comment: @Stefano Balzarotti What it is made of is irrelevant. I use dark matter only to illustrate that it does not have to conform to the limitations of normal matter.

Comment: @Alexander Again I reiterate, the only restriction that I understand is currently in place on exceeding 'c' is that information and matter can not travel faster than 'c'. What I am after is some principle that declares 'something' beyond information and mass are also limited to below 'c' speeds, and that 'something' specifically is some form 'crystal growth', whatever that 'crystal' is.

Comment: @Alexander I think I understand your reference to 'science' and 'existing'. It is indeed like I said at the end of my comment, 'quantum decoherence'. Science doesn't exist until it is brought into the 'classical world', whereupon it is defined and measurable. Or should that be 'anthropic world'?

Comment: This isn't related to [Thiotimoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiotimoline), is it?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond sorry, but really I can't imagine a crystal, made of bosons. A boson is a mediator of elementary force. I am not saying that is impossible, but I think it has no sense.A crystal is a solid structure and I  don't think that bosons can be solid. Think to a crystal made of fotons... anyway even bosons can't travel faster than c.

Comment: @IronEagle But Thiotimoline DOES exist. I have seen the research! But it has to be kept in a room with zero humidity. Even breathing near it causes it to dissolve,

Comment: @Stefano Balzarotti Who said anything about bosons? I certainly didn't. Are you positing that dark matter is made of bosons? Do you have evidence? But like I said, nothing is traveling. Nothing moves from A to B. It is the boundary that is moving, not the material.

Comment: See  'Newfound Wormhole Allows Information to Escape Black Holes' https://www.quantamagazine.org/newfound-wormhole-allows-information-to-escape-black-holes-20171023/ 'In his 1994 popular science book, Black Holes and Time Warps, Kip Thorne celebrated the style of reasoning involved in wormhole research. “No type of thought experiment pushes the laws of physics harder than the type triggered by Carl Sagan’s phone call to me,” he wrote; “thought experiments that ask, ‘What things do the laws of physics permit an infinitely advanced civilization to do, and what things do the laws forbid?’”'

Answer (score 24):

Information can't travel faster than c. That's what the implication of light speed boils down to.

Crystal formation faster than c would require that atoms at some great distance change position/structure before any "signal" could reach them to let them know to do so. While they might spontaneously crystallize on their own, it wouldn't necessarily be in an orientation with the crystallization that will soon catch up with them.

Basically you just can't trick light speed. Imagine you had a steel rod that was 4 light years long. You want to tell someone at Alpha Centauri that you'll be visiting in 4 years and you want them to bake you a cake. You have infinite strength, you push the rod, they see it move, and voila... FTL communications, right? They have 4 years to prepare.

But alas, no. This steel rod will take far longer than 4 years for him to see it "push" on the far end. The "push" only propagates along the steel rod at the speed of sound in steel (or something like that). The universe has it in for us.

Your question is flawed. In the absence of a phenomenon which is shown to be FTL or FTL-like, crystal formation cannot propagate faster than the speed of light. Quantum tunneling isn't magic wormhole technology and it does not occur faster than light. The spooky thing about it is that particles appear to go through barriers without penetrating or going around them... but they still require some sub-c time to do the tunneling.

If your creepy friend can walk through solid doors, he still takes 35 minutes to drive across town to perform the trick.

Whether there are implications where crystals form *across barriers* where the atoms don't actually come into contact I cannot say. That sounds fringey but not impossible.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104905/discussion-on-answer-by-john-o-can-a-crystal-grow-or-propagate-faster-than-c).

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what you mean by propagate. Phase velocity for an EM wave can be greater than c.

https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=16704&t=faster-than-speed-of-light

Nothing is actually traveling faster than light. This makes intuitive sense if you looks at a wave machine, like in this classic video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DovunOxlY1k

The waves don't actually move along the ladder, the dots are just going up and down. The "velocity" of the wave moving along the machine is just an illusion.

We could also think of the funny observation of a laser point on the Moon "traveling" faster than c. Sit on the Earth with a laser pointer that is sufficiently powerful as to show up on the Moon as a point. Flick it around. If you were on the Moon and considered the point to be an actual object, it would appear to be moving around with great velocity, perhaps even faster than 'c.'Of course, you know that it isn't *really* an object. The photons are all coming from Earth and obeying the speed limit. But since they are all in flight simultaneously, the point where they intersect the surface of the Moon can "move" faster than 'c.'

I don't know much about crystal growth, but it strikes me that if you had some medium that would crystallize when hit by the laser, or when interacting with (say for example) the peak of an EM wave, it could appear to grow faster than 'c' under the influence of either of these phenomenon. Information about the lattice orientation would have to be propagated I guess, but perhaps that could be carried by the laser?

Note that all of these mechanism in essence require setting up a thing in advance that will come to fruition in multiple places such that the crystallization *appears* to be propagating faster than c. No information can travel faster than c, no matter what quantum effects you want to throw in there.

Comment: Your answer is extremely useful. The concept of this crystal growth, as proposed, is that entangled particles or particles that have 'tunneled' are the cause of the crystallization. Therefore, if two particles crystallized effectively at the same time, but were a distance apart, it would appear like the crystal growth exceeded the speed of 'c'. The essence of the question was that, indeed, no information was transferred. And, as I made clear, this is NOT 'normal' crystal growth. It is NOT mediated by limitations on 'normal matter' crystal formation. No knowledge of crystal growth needed.

Comment: '...require setting up a thing in advance...' But it doesn't have to be a specific thing for a specific crystal, it could be a generic thing for ANY crystal, for ANY 'seed point'? Like saturating a solution with salt, and causing a seed point to occur anywhere in the solution?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond, it's a little tricker than that. If an observer can control *when* crystallization occurs, then no, it can't all crystallize at once, because that would be transmitting information FTL. It has to either be random, or controlled by some process that was set in motion previously which obeys the light speed limit.

Comment: I'm also a big fan of VSauce's [What is the speed of dark?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTvcpdfGUtQ) which explores the same situations.

Comment: @Matthew  The observer is just controlling when the first seed crystal has changed. Everything else beyond that is no longer under observer control. It is all just a 'natural' process, the same way that the growth of the crystal in the heat  pack is not under user control once the process is started.

Comment: @Cort Ammon I remember that concept. It spawned quite a few sci-fi articles back in the days. It was a really interesting take on the concept of a 'black light'. In one short story, someone developed a way to turn 'dark' on, instead of turning the lights off. It was a concept that really made one consider our anthropic perspective and our cognitive confirmation bias - we tend to seek facts that support our first impressions, and ignore those that contradict them.

Comment: @Matthew It is the same concept of an avalanche flowing down a hillside. Does the leading edge of that avalanche transfer information about the big boom that set it off in the first place?

Comment: That depends. If the boom (the *cause*) happened at the top of the mountain, then yes, it does, ergo the avalanche cannot "spread" at FTL speeds. OTOH if the cause was at some distance, then the edge *could* "travel" at FTL speed. For example, if I beam a signal into space to two points which are 10ly and 12ly from me, but 6ly apart, then that information can be said to "spread" at 3c, but the *cause* did not propagate FTL.

Comment: If the observer *caused* crystallization to start, then it can't happen FTL. But AFAIK nothing prevents the whole thing from spontaneously crystallizing, *if* there is no *cause* (i.e. it just happens randomly). Again, IIUC this is how QE works; two particles do the same thing at the same time despite distance between them, but because an observer can't influence *what/when* they do whatever, causality is not violated.

Comment: @Matthew So 'if I beam a light into space at two points  which are 10ly and 12ly from me, but 6ly apart, then that information can be said to "spread" at 3c, ' and each of those light beams causes a point to crystalize, then it can be said that the crystal 'spread' at 3c? Why is that any different than entanglement at those points from my position? What is the difference between beaming a laser and entanglement?

Comment: @Matthew Please read my references to current experiments on entanglement. Especially the ones being conducted in China.There was a time lag between one particle changing and the entangled particle changing, but it was in the order of 10,000 times faster than 'c'.They did it repeatedly over a 12 hour period so it was not a one-off fluke, nor just a random event. It was intentional and it was caused. And it was over a 15.3 km distance.

Comment: This board isn't really a great place to get advice on current actual experiments and theories. I'm not a physicist, just an engineer. My knowledge of physics is mostly a bunch of rules of thumb, to say "is this result actually plausible? Well, something went faster than c. Is it really a thing, did it carry information? Maybe this is ok if not." The reason I like this board is that it is a fun game to play -- if we break *this one* rule, does this idea make sense with the rest?

Comment: I'm generally suspicious of information carrying wormholes because they seem to violate the basic principle of causality, but if that's the rule you want to break for your fictional universe... lots of fiction breaks that rule, because the inability to have events on far flung planets impact each other is a Total Storytelling Bummer. If you want to have a wormhole driven crystal formation mechanic that runs faster than c in your universe, I think that is a very cool and unique idea. I think you can justify it with vague quantum waveform technobabble and your readers will go along with it.

Comment: Perhaps you could also have a superintelligent AI that predicts human movements and generates waveforms that come to fruition in a manner that appears to the confused protagonists to be faster than c. The fact that it isn't breaking any known laws of physics could be a Big Reveal that allows the protagonists to dramatically overcome it.

Comment: @Zwuwdz See my response to cmaster in puppetsock answer, as to a plausible mechanic that does NOT cause information or matter to travel faster than 'c'. No wormholes or quantum entanglement necessary. I used these only as examples. This question arose from the question about containing a vacuum bubble growing at speed 'c', by forming a containment vessel around it, except that some trigger mechanism would be needed.

Comment: Incidentally did you see my reference  'That is, we demonstrated Einstein’s ‘spooky action at a distance’ in that Bob’s quantum state (of his half of a single photon) was probably dependent on Alice’s choice of measurement (on the other half), and could not have been pre-existing. Quantitatively, we violated a multisetting nonlinear EPR-steering inequality by several s.d.’s (0.042±0.006).' from nature.com/articles/ncomms7665 Blows the notion that causality has a speed limit out of the water. Now, for backwards causality. Something NOW caused something BACK THEN to happen.

Comment: 'Retrocausality is associated with the Double Inferential state-Vector Formalism (DIVF), later known as the two-state vector formalism (TSVF) in quantum mechanics, where the present is characterised by quantum states of the past and the future taken in combination.[17][18]' from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrocausality Being an engineer rather than a physics 'expert' with out-of-date knowledge could be an advantage.

Answer (score 4):

The specific question that can be answered is, can the crystal *propagate* at faster than c. That is, if it started growing at some disturbed location and spread out from there, could it exceed c.

The answer to that is a flat no. Crystals operate on electromagnetism. Electrons and positively charged nuclei. If you get a crystal *really* exotic you might possibly bring in some weak nuclear.

These forces operate at a maximum of the speed of light. This is backed up by more than one century of experimentation. Winner and still Heavy Weight Champion of the World, Relativity.

Comment: The OP suggested some sort of quantum principle of growth, not the usual mechanisms. John O's answer is correct, although it might be possible *if* the formation of the crystal is random. If it can be triggered, then doing so would make FTL communication possible. (However, that would be less "growing/propagating" and more spontaneous formation over a large area. For that matter, this would seem consistent with quantum entanglement...)

Comment: It was a *tedious* homework assignment in my first year of grad school. But QM does not permit information to travel faster than light. So, no, can't be done.

Comment: I have two entangled particles separated by 1LY. I observe some property of one of them. Due to entanglement, I *know* that the other is in the same state. As I understand it, this is how QE works... but *it doesn't transmit information*. If I understand this correctly (and it's plausible I don't), then I think spontaneous crystal formation would also be plausible. Again, the key is that *formation* does not *transmit* information. This means I also can't *influence* formation, because that *would* allow information to be transmitted.

Comment: @Matthew It's waaaay outside this SE. But, no, you don't know that at all.  What you get is Bell's theorem.  You look for, for example, plus or minus. If you sit measuring your end, you get *exactly* the same results no matter what is happening at the other end. There is no change whatever in your observations regardless of what the other observer does. You cannot tell if the other observer is even present.

Comment: ...and this contradicts what I said *how*? I sit at my end starting at the crystal medium which either has or has not crystalized. At the other end, it also either has or has not crystalized. Assuming I haven't poked it (broken whatever QE is at play), then if my end is crystalized, so is the other end. The crystalization "spread" FTL. But *no information* traveled FTL. Information can *spread* FTL (note Zwuwdz's answer), but can't *travel* FTL.

Comment: @Matthew You said "I know that the other is in the same state." No, you don't. You don't even know if there *is* another observer. You sit and take your readings, you get a random series of + and -. You get this if the other observer measures. Or if he does not. Or if he turns his device 90 degrees to yours. Or if he performs his measurement one light year farther away or closer. Or if he takes his device and smashes it. You *don't* know the other particle is in the same state.

Comment: @Matthew A breath of fresh air. You understand the concept - no information is being transferred. Many seem to be hung up on this. If there is no transfer of information, then no violation. The question is, therefore, 'does this crystal growth transfer information'? And if so, what information does it transfer?

Comment: @puppetsock Two things. First, quantum entanglement can now be read without destroying the entanglement, and second, the quantum state can be 'changed' without destroying the entanglement. You need a thicker physics textbook.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Yes, the crystal growth does transfer information: a) the information that the crystal is growing, and that the atoms should get in line, and b) the information about the orientation of the growing crystal in space. So, unless you manage to put your system into a fully entangled state beforehand with the superposition of all possible crystal orientations, and the trigger is just measuring that orientation locally, you won't get around the information travel theorem. And even in that case, the setting up of the entangled state would be the actual growing of the crystal.

Comment: @cmaster - reinstate monica  Let's do a thought experiment. Two rigid knives are floating through space, one LY long. They are moving together, except at a slight angle to each other. The far end of one rod is 10cm further than the near ends. As they cross in space, only ne plank constant apart, the point of intersection obviously would appear to travel from the near end to the far end much faster than the speed 'c'. But no information travels along the intersection that wasn't known before.

Comment: Now suppose that, when these two blades crossed at one plank constant distance  apart, it caused particles along the length to change and 'crystalize'. Easily conjectured, because one plank constant separation would be within the bounds of the width pf a particle.  Would you say that the crystal grew at a speed faster than 'c'? Would you then say information traveled along the shear lines faster than 'c'?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Some misunderstandings about the thought experiment you sketch: a) From the point of view of either of the two rods, the other rod is moving towards itself at a low relativistic speed. There are only relative speeds in relativity. b) Yes, the point of contact between the rods may move along its length faster than light. However, no information is transferred along because each part of the rod crashes into the other rod independently of the other parts.

Comment: c) The faster-than-light travel of the contact point works because movement happens along another dimension. Crystals are 3D, though, so you lack a fourth dimension in which the triggering *thing* may be moving. Really, crystallization is an effect of strict locality: An atom cannot enter the grid of a crystal until it actually collides with some atoms that are already part of the crystal. And only once it is fixed to the crystal can it help other atoms to find their place as well. That is information transfer in its purest form.

Comment: @cmaster - reinstate monica 'No information is transferred'. Exactly my point. No misunderstanding. You are using a conventional understanding of crystal formation in normal matter. I specifically eliminated this as a criteria. This is NOT 'normal crystal formation in normal matter'. Nevertheless, the formation WOULD be a 'local matter'. The closeness or proximity of the two plates, locally, interacting, locally. Not dependent on what happened beside it. But serendipitously, the particle beside it just happens, at that instant, to be in the optimal position to bond.

Answer (score 4):

Crystal growth cannot propogate faster than light in anyway that would transfer information. In other words, imagine there are two points in the crystal medium, A and B, distance d apart. Point B cannot crystallize because of any event at point A that didn't occur at least d / c units of time in the past, otherwise information has been tranfered faster than light. Specifically, an observer at B could know someone initiated crystalization at A sooner than they would know from a light speed signal.

However, there's nothing prohibiting the entire crystal medium from crystalizing simultaneously if the above restriction is respected. For instance, in a pool of crystal medium of diameter x, it's possible that "intiating crystallization" at any point in the pool has no observable effect until x / c units of time later, at which point the entire pool crystallizes at once. No information would be transfered faster than light, because an observer at one end of the pool would know it was going to crystalize before it actually did if a light speed signal was sent from the other end when the crystalization was initiated. I have no idea what mechanism might cause this, but since no information would be transfered, it's theoretically possible.

Comment: So you are saying that in an entangled pair A and B, B can not be defined by A until a time period d/c elapses, yet they occur instantaneously. Methinks your physics textbook that you are consulting is not yet thick enough, and is missing chapters on quantum physics. 'Entanglement' is not limited to 'c' because no information is transmitted, not because there is a law that says a related change in two things a distance apart can not occur at the same time.

Comment: 'Specifically, an observer at B could know someone initiated crystalization at A sooner...'  Likewise when traveling using worm holes, an observer at B could somehow know someone initiated travel at A sooner than they would know from a light speed signal. Yet wormhole travel is generally accepted as feasible and non-contradictory to the existing physics text book. If I posited an infinite number of worm holes, connecting all of the particles in the crystal, and the 'signal' traveled through these worm holes to every crystalized 'particle', as a thought experiment, what would be your retort?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond Entaglement does not transfer any information. An observer of particle B would have no indication whether or not particle A has been manipulated. If you still think entanglement transmits information, try to devise a scheme to send a sequence of bits FTL using entanglement; it's not possible. Wormholes, on the other hand, warp space. If a light speed signal took the same shortest path, through the wormholes, it would arrive no later than the front of crystallization. This might cause crystallization that appears to propogate FTL, but it's not true to say it actually does.

Comment: 'Entaglement does not transfer any information'. That is speculation, as recent developments do not support this. However, even if true, it does not contradict the question 'Is there any limitation on the speed of anything OTHER than information or matter'? If one accepts that entanglement does not transfer information nor matter, then one has to accept that there can be 'something else' besides information and matter that IS 'transferred', unbounded by the limitation of 'c'.

Comment: Your physics textbook is out of date. Please reference https://futurism.com/chinese-physicists-measure-speed-of-quantum-entanglement-2 'These receiving units, named Alice and Bob, were positioned 15.3 km apart in an east-west orientation ... The team then observed the first half of the entangled pair and waited to see how quickly the other half assumed the same state. They repeated this process for over 12 hours to help ensure accuracy of their measurements.'

Comment: Also see https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/150207-chinese-physicists-measure-speed-of-einsteins-spooky-action-at-a-distance-at-least-10000-times-faster-than-light 'Chinese physicists measure speed of Einstein’s ‘spooky action at a distance’: At least 10,000 times faster than light' and that was SEVEN YEARS AGO.

Comment: From the cited article 'We’re now at the point where a quantum internet — either using conventional fiber or satellites — is starting to become feasible. If it turns out that we actually can communicate data via quantum entanglement, we now know that it’ll be much faster than the speed of light.'

Comment: 'No information would be transfered faster than light, because an observer at one end of the pool would know it was going to crystalize before it actually did if a light speed signal was sent from the other end when the crystalization was initiated.' isn't this exactly the same scenario as wormhole travel?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond To be honest, the articles you're citing look very lackluster in terms of scientific rigor. I would dig into the actual papers they're referencing to figure out what they're misinterpreting/exaggerating, but there are zero links to any actual sources and they don't even mention the author names and year. I'm not an expert in this field but I'm fairly certain that the consensus is still that entanglement cannot transmit information (see the no communication theorem). Just disparaging peoples' textbooks while linking pop science articles is not convincing me otherwise.

Comment: @el duderino So just because the experiments prove your understanding to be wrong, it is the experiments that are faulty, not you understanding. And when the results are replicated, it is still faulty science. And when the experiments are conducted between earth and a satellite, with the same results, your understanding is still valid over demonstrated factual evidence. In that case, at what point does your 'understanding' become 'religious fervor'? Just curious.

Comment: @el duderino Here is a link to the actual citation of the paper.

Comment: @el duderino Here is a link to the source paper from a very credible source, affiliated with NASA, https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013PhRvL.110z0407Y/abstract This is much more than just 'pop sci'.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond That article's findings don't imply information is trasmitted FTL. [This answer on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/61166/108892), explains the type of experiment. The authors of the article assume the third interpretation laid out in the answer, and find a lower bound for the speed of the "interaction". The authors aditionally demonstrate their result is independent of orientation. Note that this interaction, if it exists, *cannot* form crystals in a way that transmits information. The two cases in my answer still hold.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond My argument isn't that "the experiments are faulty," it that **your** understanding of what they're proving is. I went through the actual paper, and also the version published as a PRL which is much more polished and clear in its language. As I expected, it says nothing about transferring information and instead is a standard test of Bell’s inequality that was set up so that the measurements at the two legs of the apparatus occurred within very close times in the lab frame.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond (cont) If you then divide the distance between the two measurement apparatuses (with some SR adjustments tossed in) by this time difference you get a speed much greater than the speed of light. But this speed is not the speed of information transfer or of anything physical-- the notion that it is is based on faulty intuition arising from classical physics.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond (cont) As is argued by me, Vaelus, virtually every physicist, and even the second pop-sci article you linked (the extremetech one), you can mathematically prove that entanglement alone cannot be used to transmit information within the framework of QM. The article you linked does not convince me otherwise because it doesn’t argue otherwise.

Comment: @Vaelus  So something posted on StackExchange has more authority than something that is written in a recognized, accepted professional journal?

Comment: @el duderino Is THIS clear enough? 'That is, we demonstrated Einstein’s ‘spooky action at a distance’ in that Bob’s quantum state (of his half of a single photon) was probably dependent on Alice’s choice of measurement (on the other half), and could not have been pre-existing. Quantitatively, we violated a multisetting nonlinear EPR-steering inequality by several s.d.’s (0.042±0.006).' from https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms7665